# Bandwidth consumption of Amazon S3 bucket mounted with S3fs on a VPS

Tags: vps, wordpress, amazon-s3, bandwidth, s3fs

I have :

- VPS server on Vultr with web server and Wordpress installed.
- Uploads folder is mounted on Amazon S3 bucket using s3fs.

If a user downloads a 1GB file from my website will the traffic be served to him from Amazon S3 directly or it will be passed through the vps. Because I want to offload bandwidth and I would like to know if it will be counted as 1GB or 1GB + 1GB.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not a Wordpress expert, but what do those file URLs look like from the user POV - are you rewriting them somehow?

In other words, when users download a file, is the URL on your website pointing to something like https://.s3.amazonaws.com/<path_to_file>, or is rather something like https://<your_wordpress_domain>/<path_to_file>?

In case of the former: just 1GB (due to direct download from S3), otherwise: 1GB+1GB (because of your VPS proxying the download).